# how to keep my room dust-free?

Tags: cleaning, home, dust

I live in Apartment 5th floor . There is only one window, only me , less windy, I always lock the door but still so dusty. In the end I even attached net for whole window but still same ? All over the table , floor. Any Suggestions for preventing dust from entering my room. or any other methods for long period dust-free room

Location: India... Building constructed : 4 years ago....brick & cement type building...Renovated:1 yearr ago(ceiling, flooring & painting)

Comment: I don't understand exactly.  The dust is coming from outside the house?

Comment: I don't understand either. Are you trying to troubleshoot where the (apparently excessive?) dust is coming from, or looking for effective methods of dusting your room?

Comment: Depends on the dust. In spring, for example, the air here is full of pollen, but it sticks in the mosquito nets. I just wash them when the pollen stops.

Comment: I don't see why you think a net would stop dust entering a room.  You need a HEPA filter.

Answer (score 2):

You said apartment, makes me think building, and probably somewhat old. I am accustomed to old buildings, and they're usually very dusty from old timbers of wood on the ceiling etc. Best you could do is probably clean your walls, ceiling and high ledges - anywhere that might have dust buildup continually trickling down. That should help for a good while.

Answer (score 1):

I live in an old (100+ year-old) wooden New England house.  We've tightened it up over the years, but it still gets very dusty.  I have a dust and mold allergy and have experimented with a number of filters.  Any good HEPA filter will probably work, though these days I like the (very affordable) Holmes Desktop Air Purifier like this:

[image]

I let it run 24/7 and it does a pretty good job of keeping the dust down.  Note that it's on the quiet side, though certainly not whisper quiet; it will seem a bit loud at night.

I like the version with both the HEPA filter and optional ionizer.  The HEPA filter traps dust in a filter layer.  The ionizer charges dust particles so that they settle down to the floor where they can be vacuumed up.

There are some concerns about the negative health effects of ionizing / ozone generation, so I only run the ionizer when I'm not in the room for a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

The building doesn't seem to be that old, so its unlikely to be the construction or drafts from the window or door, unless the building shakes regularly because its near, say, a train line causing vibration. Otherwise, not much you can do - most of the dust comes off you I'm afraid, so unless you can get undressed in a different room, shower, then dressed again before entering your room, you can't reduce it much. Clothes themselves contribute dander and dust  to the air too, so the only way to create a relatively dust free environnment would be to remove all soft materials and fabrics, keep your clothes elsewhere and dress/undress elsewhere.

If you're not keeping fabrics like clothing in closed cupboards or drawers, that will make the dust worse too.